# How to order a stack bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to order a stacked geom_bar or geom_col by the height of the bars but arranging my dataset or using "reorder()" inside the aesthetics of ggplot  is not working, so looking for some help. This is my dataset

```
df
Roost  NGen Sex  
   <chr> <int> <chr>
 1 A1        2 unkwn
 2 A1        3 M    
 3 A1       10 F    
 4 A2        2 M    
 5 A2        3 F    
 6 AA1      12 unkwn
 7 AA1      24 M    
 8 AA1      29 F    
 9 AC-01     4 M    
10 AC-01     5 unkwn
```

When i plot it using:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= Roost, y= NGen, fill= Sex))+ geom_col()+  coord_flip()
```

The bars are ordered by the name of the roost and not the height of the bars

Picture on this link   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUquZ.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS7SB.png  (i can't insert pictures as i do not have enough "reputation" points as a new user.)

I have tried the following code to try to organise the columns by height

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= reorder(Roost,NGen), y= NGen, fill= Sex))+ geom_col()+  coord_flip()
```

The code does organise the data in some fashion generating the following graph

[image]

However, as you can see the bars are not organised by height. The outcome is the same if i use geom_bar or geom_col.

I have also tried converting Roost into factors and converting NGen to numeric and using `aes(x= fct_reorder(Roost,NGen), y= NGen, fill= Sex)` but I haven't got the desired outcome.

Any clues are greatly appreciated

Cheers,

Diana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the sum of `NGen` for each `Roost`, `arrange` the data based on sum, assign factor levels and then plot the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(Roost) %>%
  mutate(NGen_s = sum(NGen)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(NGen_s) %>%
  mutate(Roost = factor(Roost, unique(Roost))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= Roost, y= NGen, fill= Sex)) + 
  geom_col() +  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Ronak. This works perfectly and i wouldn't have thought of doing it that way.